# Creating a method in a Class which takes dummy arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I am kind of new to object oriented programming and want to explore it more. I have a dictionary here  "a" which has certain key value pairs. So what I would like to do is build a method which goes through this dictionary and takes only the values which have their values as True

I tried creating a class which takes in the values, i have the logic for checking the values in the dict but dont understand how to proceed with creating a method out of it

a = {"A": True, "B": False, "C": True}

```
class Check:

    def __init__(self, country, A, B):
         self.country = country
         self.A = A
         self.B = B

    def countrycheck(self):

        Result = {}
        for i in self.country:
            if self.country[i] == True:
                Result.update({i: True})

        return Result
```

I get results but not cannot formulate what I actually want. I want it to run something like this:

```
trial = Check(a, b, c)
```

So running this should give me a dict = {"A": True, "C": True}. 
a is where I check for the country values from the dict and I also want the b and c arguments to be there. I tried using them but it gives me this error - "b is not defined"

Comment: This doesn't even look like it should be a class. If you just make this a function it'll make more sense. And did you intend `b` to be "b"? Where is it defined?

Comment: `trial = Check(a, b, c)` only gives you an instance of class `Check`. To get the result, you should run `trial.countrycheck()`

Answer (score 1):

function **init**(), is always executed when the class is being initiated.

Use the **init**() function to assign values to object properties, or other operations that are necessary to do when the object is being created. in your case A,B in  `def __init__(self, country, A, B):` doesnt have sense

Note: The self parameter is a reference to the current instance of the class, and is used to access variables that belongs to the class.

Object Methods:

Objects can also contain methods. Methods in objects are functions that belongs to the object.

If you want to use the method (or attribute) of a class outside the definition of that class you will do it like:

```
trial = Check(a)

trial.countrycheck()
```

Example:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print ('Foo')

    def bar(self, argument):
        print ('Bar ', argument)

a = A()
a.foo() #prints 'Foo'
a.bar('Arg!') #prints 'Bar Arg!'
```

your code should look like:

```
class Check:
    def __init__(self, country):
         self.country = country

    def countrycheck(self):

        Result = {}
        for i in self.country:
            if self.country[i] == True:
                Result.update({i: True})

        return Result


a = {"A": True, "B": False, "C": True}

trial = Check(a)

print (trial.countrycheck())
```

output:

```
{'A': True, 'C': True}
```